# Issues while recreating a TIFF file with 1D encoded data

Tags: c, tiff, huffman-code, image-compression, run-length-encoding

This is regarding Fax Image compression. Initially I had an Uncompressed TIFF file , I wrote a code to extract its tags and the Image data present in it. Once I extracted the image data I performed **1D modefied Huffman coding/ Run length coding** on it to get the **encoded compressed data** which I have stored in a textfile.

Now I am trying to recreate a TIFF file by modifying the tags appropriately to store the encoded compressed data. I have writen a code to recreate the tiff file and when I open the tiff file with an appliction to view all the tags, I find that all the tags I have put are correctly being read. However, when I use an online tiff viewer I do not get the correct image. I am confident that my encoded data is correct according to the Huffman Runlength tables. Anyone has any idea why I am not able to view the same Image with my compressed tiff file?

Note : I have not used any C libraries such as libtiff, The tiff file is just created by opening a tiff file and writing specific values at different offsets based on the tiff file stucture.

Thank you.

[**The Original Uncompressed file**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU6ru.png)

[**The 1D encoded compressed file**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFuQ2.png)

Comment: What is the size in pixels of the image? "Real" fax images were normally 1728 pixels wide, and while I seem to remember there were extensions (it was a long time since I wrote fax software!), "odd" size images _might_ be a problem. Also possible is that while the tags are "correct", the offsets to the data might not be.

Comment: Hey @TripeHound , The Image is a black and white bilevel image which is 1728 Pixels wide and 2707 pixels long. I have also rechecked my work and I believe that I have written the data back at the correct offset matching with the stripoffset tag that I created. However I would like to give some more details about how I wrote the data into the tiff file at the specific offset. So I have text file which conists of Codewords for each scanline of the image followed by fill bits and the EOL codeword. So I just went to specic offset in the tiff file and wrote each character from the textfile to it.